# Delete all conflicts in pouchDB

Tags: couchdb, indexeddb, pouchdb

my problem is to sync between **pouch** and **couchDB**.
I will manage to get my documents from couchDb and check in the pouch if there is already an existing document. So, if we have a **conflict** I want so solve the conflict on the **client-side**. But I don't know how to check if there is a conflict or not.
Is there any way to check the pouchDb for given conflicts (after inserting or during inserting documents) and solve them.

greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [pouch-resolve-conflicts](https://github.com/jo/pouch-resolve-conflicts) plugin, which offers a simple API for resolving conflicts. :)

And yes, you need to do it individually for all docs. So you can do an `allDocs()` beforehand in order to fetch them.

Comment: Thx, I think this will help me. But  as far as I understand it's not possible to to fetch the database with `db.replicate.from(...)` and get conflicts. Conflicts will only show up if you fetch documents?!

Comment: okay, thats maybe the problem, why i did not get any conflict...
Thx!